# How do I trim a file extension from a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, process

What's the most efficient way to trim the suffix in Java, like this:

```
title part1.txt
title part2.html
=>
title part1
title part2
```

Comment: efficient code wise, is what you mean i hope, not CPU wise

Comment: He wasn't asking how to do it, he was asking what's the most efficient way.  I came here looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 317):

This is the sort of code that we shouldn't be doing ourselves. Use libraries for the mundane stuff, save your brain for the hard stuff.

In this case, I recommend using [FilenameUtils.removeExtension()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#removeExtension%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)

Comment: For 95% of the projects, this should be the accepted answer. Rewriting code like this is the root cause for many headaches!

Comment: Just add the following line in gradle to add the depedency:-

compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'

Comment: If you have Apache Commons I/O already in your project, that's right. But if this all you need from it, you're adding (at least) 2.5 MB of dead weight to your project for something that can be easily done with a single line.

Comment: Good luck doing it in a single line so that it succeeds on even the obvious edge cases

Comment: heads-up that this won't work if the file has two extensions ie. filename.csv.zip

Answer (score 259):

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Comment: This should be assigned to a new variable as str is not modified.

Comment: Handle with care: it'll throw an Exception at you if the file name has no suffix.

Comment: what about archive.tar.bz2 ?

Comment: `if(str.contains("."))` `str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'))`

Comment: What if str is null ? FilenameUtils.removeExtension is null-safe

Comment: if(str != null && str.contains(".")) str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.')). FilenameUtils is another dependency, and not always available

Comment: Awesome for something neat, and that doesn't require some third party stuff.

Comment: @NicolasTyler What if `str` did not have an extension and had something like `myFile.withoutAnExtension` as its name? Or if it was `.htaccess` or `.nomedia`

Comment: @Spikatrix I am sure there are many error checks you can add. Maybe something like this? `int index = str.lastIndexOf('.'); if (index == -1 || index == 0) return str; else return str.substring(0, index);`

Comment: What would you get for this file: "direcotry.new/filename" which is regular file name without extension placed in a directory where name has dot in it?

Answer (score 94):

As using the `String.substring` and `String.lastIndex` in a one-liner is good, there are some issues in terms of being able to cope with certain file paths.

Take for example the following path:

```
a.b/c
```

Using the one-liner will result in:

```
a
```

That's incorrect.

The result should have been `c`, but since the file lacked an extension, but the path had a directory with a `.` in the name, the one-liner method was tricked into giving part of the path as the filename, which is not correct.

**Need for checks**

Inspired by [skaffman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java/990408#990408), I took a look at the [`FilenameUtils.removeExtension`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#removeExtension(java.lang.String)) method of the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

In order to recreate its behavior, I wrote a few tests the new method should fulfill, which are the following:

```
Path                  Filename
--------------        --------
a/b/c                 c
a/b/c.jpg             c
a/b/c.jpg.jpg         c.jpg

a.b/c                 c
a.b/c.jpg             c
a.b/c.jpg.jpg         c.jpg

c                     c
c.jpg                 c
c.jpg.jpg             c.jpg
```

(And that's all I've checked for -- there probably are other checks that should be in place that I've overlooked.)

**The implementation**

The following is my implementation for the `removeExtension` method:

```
public static String removeExtension(String s) {

    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String filename;

    // Remove the path upto the filename.
    int lastSeparatorIndex = s.lastIndexOf(separator);
    if (lastSeparatorIndex == -1) {
        filename = s;
    } else {
        filename = s.substring(lastSeparatorIndex + 1);
    }

    // Remove the extension.
    int extensionIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (extensionIndex == -1)
        return filename;

    return filename.substring(0, extensionIndex);
}
```

Running this `removeExtension` method with the above tests yield the results listed above.

The method was tested with the following code. As this was run on Windows, the path separator is a `\` which must be escaped with a `\` when used as part of a `String` literal.

```
System.out.println(removeExtension("a\\b\\c"));
System.out.println(removeExtension("a\\b\\c.jpg"));
System.out.println(removeExtension("a\\b\\c.jpg.jpg"));

System.out.println(removeExtension("a.b\\c"));
System.out.println(removeExtension("a.b\\c.jpg"));
System.out.println(removeExtension("a.b\\c.jpg.jpg"));

System.out.println(removeExtension("c"));
System.out.println(removeExtension("c.jpg"));
System.out.println(removeExtension("c.jpg.jpg"));
```

The results were:

```
c
c
c.jpg
c
c
c.jpg
c
c
c.jpg
```

The results are the desired results outlined in the test the method should fulfill.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a particular reason why you use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` and not just `File.separator`?

Comment: A word of warning: This solution also removes the preceding path, not just the extension, unlike the Apache Commons IO method.

Comment: It appears this will fail for the `/path/to/.htaccess`

Answer (score 19):

```
String foo = "title part1.txt";
foo = foo.substring(0, foo.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: No, there might be more than one '.'; you want lastIndexOf('.')

Comment: -1 for not using the method I thought you were using. That's now a total of +0 from me. Change it quick! ;)

Answer (score 19):

BTW, in my case, when I wanted a quick solution to remove a specific extension, this is approximately what I did:

```
  if (filename.endsWith(ext))
    return filename.substring(0,filename.length() - ext.length());
  else
    return filename;
```

Answer (score 11):

Use a method in `com.google.common.io.Files` class if your project is already dependent on Google core library. The method you need is `getNameWithoutExtension`.

Comment: Why someone is against my answer??

Comment: Note that this returns the base name only, so the path is also removed: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getNameWithoutExtension(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 11):

you can try this function , very basic

```
public String getWithoutExtension(String fileFullPath){
    return fileFullPath.substring(0, fileFullPath.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Comment: What if you have c:\directory.old/filenoext ?

Answer (score 9):

```
String fileName="foo.bar";
int dotIndex=fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if(dotIndex>=0) { // to prevent exception if there is no dot
  fileName=fileName.substring(0,dotIndex);
}
```

Is this a trick question? :p

I can't think of a faster way atm.

Comment: Works in general since lastIndexOf('.') works exactly the same way for both path types. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, the question assumes that there is an extension, so you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

I found [coolbird's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java/990492#990492) particularly useful.

But I changed the last result statements to:

```
if (extensionIndex == -1)
  return s;

return s.substring(0, lastSeparatorIndex+1) 
         + filename.substring(0, extensionIndex);
```

as I wanted the full path name to be returned.

```
So "C:\Users\mroh004.COM\Documents\Test\Test.xml" becomes 
   "C:\Users\mroh004.COM\Documents\Test\Test" and not
   "Test"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.'), filename.length()).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Opposite of what was asked and there is no need to pass the length, just use one arg substring

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex.  This one replaces the last dot, and everything after it.

```
String baseName = fileName.replaceAll("\\.[^.]*$", "");
```

You can also create a Pattern object if you want to precompile the regex.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Spring you could use

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.stripFilenameExtension(String path)
```

> Strip the filename extension from the given Java resource path, e.g.
>
> "mypath/myfile.txt" -> "mypath/myfile".
>
> Params: path – the file path
>
> Returns: the path with stripped filename extension

Comment: Thank you for posting.  For some reason, these SO posts always have an aversion to using libraries, but my project already has spring dependency and this is much more explicit and clean than writing myself

Answer (score 2):

```
 private String trimFileExtension(String fileName)
  {
     String[] splits = fileName.split( "\\." );
     return StringUtils.remove( fileName, "." + splits[splits.length - 1] );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] splitted = fileName.split(".");
String fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.replace("." + splitted[splitted.length - 1], "");
```

Comment: Need to split on `"\\."` as "." is special for regex.

Answer (score 1):

create a new file with string image path

```
String imagePath;
File test = new File(imagePath);
test.getName();
test.getPath();
getExtension(test.getName());


public static String getExtension(String uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dot >= 0) {
            return uri.substring(dot);
        } else {
            // No extension.
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils version 2.4 gives the following answer

```
public static String removeExtension(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int index = indexOfExtension(filename);
    if (index == -1) {
        return filename;
    } else {
        return filename.substring(0, index);
    }
}

public static int indexOfExtension(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int extensionPos = filename.lastIndexOf(EXTENSION_SEPARATOR);
    int lastSeparator = indexOfLastSeparator(filename);
    return lastSeparator > extensionPos ? -1 : extensionPos;
}

public static int indexOfLastSeparator(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int lastUnixPos = filename.lastIndexOf(UNIX_SEPARATOR);
    int lastWindowsPos = filename.lastIndexOf(WINDOWS_SEPARATOR);
    return Math.max(lastUnixPos, lastWindowsPos);
}

public static final char EXTENSION_SEPARATOR = '.';
private static final char UNIX_SEPARATOR = '/';
private static final char WINDOWS_SEPARATOR = '\\';
```

Answer (score 1):

The best what I can write trying to stick to the Path class:

```
Path removeExtension(Path path) {
    return path.resolveSibling(path.getFileName().toString().replaceFirst("\\.[^.]*$", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont do stress on mind guys. i did already many times. just copy paste this public static method in your staticUtils library for future uses ;-)

```
static String removeExtension(String path){
        String filename;
        String foldrpath;
        String filenameWithoutExtension;
        if(path.equals("")){return "";}
        if(path.contains("\\")){    // direct substring method give wrong result for "a.b.c.d\e.f.g\supersu"
            filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\"));
            foldrpath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('\\'));;
            if(filename.contains(".")){
                filenameWithoutExtension = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
            }else{
                filenameWithoutExtension = filename;
            }
            return foldrpath + filenameWithoutExtension;
        }else{
            return path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('.'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be using the system directory separator(s), not a hardcoded backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
String title_part = "title part1.txt";
int i;
for(i=title_part.length()-1 ; i>=0 && title_part.charAt(i)!='.' ; i--);
title_part = title_part.substring(0,i);
```

Starting to the end till the '.' then call substring.

Edit:
Might not be a golf but it's effective :)

Comment: That's basically what lastIndexOf does anyway; why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: For fun and to be a bit descriptive. just that. (and i forgot about lastIndexOf when i was writing this)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind the scenarios where there is no file extension or there is more than one file extension

example Filename : file | file.txt | file.tar.bz2

```
/**
 *
 * @param fileName
 * @return file extension
 * example file.fastq.gz => fastq.gz
 */
private String extractFileExtension(String fileName) {
    String type = "undefined";
    if (FilenameUtils.indexOfExtension(fileName) != -1) {
        String fileBaseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName);
        int indexOfExtension = -1;
        while (fileBaseName.contains(".")) {
            indexOfExtension = FilenameUtils.indexOfExtension(fileBaseName);
            fileBaseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileBaseName);
        }
        type = fileName.substring(indexOfExtension + 1, fileName.length());
    }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String img = "example.jpg";
// String imgLink = "http://www.example.com/example.jpg";
URI uri = null;

try {
    uri = new URI(img);
    String[] segments = uri.getPath().split("/");
    System.out.println(segments[segments.length-1].split("\\.")[0]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will output **example** for both **img** and **imgLink**

Answer (score 0):

```
private String trimFileName(String fileName)
    {
        String[] ext;
        ext = fileName.split("\\.");
        
        return fileName.replace(ext[ext.length - 1], "");

    }
```

This code will spilt the file name into parts where ever it has " . ", For eg. If the file name is *file-name.hello.txt* then it will be spilted into string array as , { "file-name", "hello", "txt" }. So anyhow the last element in this string array will be the file extension of that particular file , so we can simply find the last element of any arrays with `arrayname.length - 1`, so after we get to know the last element, we can just replace the file extension with an empty string in that file name. Finally this will return file-name.hello. , if you want to remove also the last period then you can add the string with only period to the last element of string array in the return line. Which should look like,

```
return fileName.replace("." +  ext[ext.length - 1], "");
```

Comment: A few words explaing how this code is supposed to help would be really useful

Comment: This will give an unexpected result for an input like `file-doc-new.marketing.doc`, as it will remove both instances of the word `doc`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String removeExtension(String file) {
    if(file != null && file.length() > 0) {
        while(file.contains(".")) {
            file = file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf('.'));
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: This will transform "a.jpg.jpg" to "a" instead of the (correct) "a.jpg". What purpose serves the `file.length() > 0` check?

Comment: Main question was "how remove extension ?", so yes its transform "a.txt.zip" to "a" and ".htaccess" to emptiness.
This function work with Strings, so file names can be not null but still can be 0 length, faster check if it worth it before parsing symbols. Regards.