# How do I get the file extension of a file in Java?

Tags: java, file, io

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for the MIME type.

Let's say I have the following input: `/path/to/file/foo.txt`

I'd like a way to break this input up, specifically into `.txt` for the extension.  Is there any built in way to do this in Java?  I would like to avoid writing my own parser.

Comment: You never know when some new platform is going to come along that defines extensions as being separated by a comma. Now you need to write platform dependent code. The Java frameworks should be more forward thinking and have APIs for getting extensions where they write the platform dependent code and you, as the user of the API, just say get the extension.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: OMG. Let's create a 100MB JRE with many thousands classes but please be sure to not implement any method which returns `"txt"` from `"filename.txt"` because some platform somewhere might want to use `"filename,txt"`.

Comment: @EricDuminil "Be sure to not implement any method which returns "txt" from "filename.txt"" ??? Try `path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."));` ..... And yeah.. They are sure to don't duplicate something for nothing...

Comment: @VelocityPulse That's *exactly* what bothers me. Since there's no standard way to get the file extension, you get dozens of half-wrong answers and slightly different implementations. Your code uses 2 methods (I would have liked to have *one* single, explicit method), it returns `".txt"` from `"filename.txt"`, which might not be the desired result, and worst of all, it fails with `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of returning an empty string if there's no extension.

Comment: Finally, there is a new method `Path#getExtension` available right in the JDK as of Java 20: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74315488/3764965

Answer (score 742, accepted):

In this case, use [FilenameUtils.getExtension](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Here is an example of how to use it (you may specify either full path or just file name):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

// ...

String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/path/to/file/foo.txt"); // returns "txt"
String ext2 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("bar.exe"); // returns "exe"
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle Groovy DSL

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
```

Gradle Kotlin DSL

```
implementation("commons-io:commons-io:2.6")
```

Others https://search.maven.org/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/jar

Comment: Should be noted that it returns only "gz" for a file named archive.tar.gz.

Comment: @Zitrax that's because "gz" is the file extension.

Comment: @zhelon [.gz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) stands for gnu zipped file, and [.tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) stands for (t)ape (ar)chive. So .tar.gz is a tar file inside a gnu zipped file, which has the .gz extension.

Comment: is path neccessary as well ?

Comment: @guru_001 No it's not of course, it's just to mention that you may call it both with full path or just file name.

Comment: @Zitrax can't have more than one extension for a file or extension name that contains dot, so in your case extension is .gz

Comment: This is the best solution because the getExtension() method is looking for the Last Separator in Unix and Windows systems.

Answer (score 374):

Do you really need a "parser" for this?

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i > 0) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```

Assuming that you're dealing with simple Windows-like file names, not something like `archive.tar.gz`.

Btw, for the case that a directory may have a '.', but the filename itself doesn't (like `/path/to.a/file`), you can do

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
int p = Math.max(fileName.lastIndexOf('/'), fileName.lastIndexOf('\\'));

if (i > p) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Sure you might need a parser/object for this, if you wanted to do more manipulations than just the extension... say if you want just the path, the parent directory, the file name (minus the extension), etc.  I'm coming from C# and .Net where we have this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_members.aspx

Comment: As you say, there are a number of things to think about, beyond just using the naive lastIndexOf("."). I would guess that Apache Commons has a method for this, which takes all of the little tricky potential problems into account.

Comment: I think `i > 0` should be changed to `i >= 0` or `i != -1`. This takes care of filenames like `.htaccess`.

Comment: New MSDN link from my comment above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Comment: This solution will fail if the file extension contains a backslash.

Comment: regardless of how simple any code snippet is... you still need to update it/maintain it/test it/make it available as a convenient dependency... much easier if there was already a lib doing all of that

Comment: On more gotcha is if file endds with a dot. Better in a lib.  if (i > p && i < (fileName.length()-1)) {
      extension = fileName.substring(i+1);

Comment: You should use `File.separatorChar` instead of `/` and `[backslash]`.

Comment: `int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.')` gives a `dereferencing possible null pointer` warning on Netbeans. Why is that?

Comment: @user1156544 because if there is no `.` it will give a null pointer exception (another reason to use a library)

Comment: "Do you really need a "parser" for this?" This is the type of question that occurs when Java (per usual) simply doesn't include the obvious things in the APIs. E.g. how about `new File(filename).getExtension()` -- that'd be cool.

Answer (score 112):

```
private String getFileExtension(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (lastIndexOf == -1) {
        return ""; // empty extension
    }
    return name.substring(lastIndexOf);
}
```

Comment: Should be noted that this returns the '.' as well, so your file extension will be '.txt' as opposed to 'txt' in some of the other answers

Comment: Better Answer and @NickEntin Better comment. To remove the period "." from the extension of the file, can be coded as
int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;

Comment: that approach may not work in some case e.g. /usr/bin/foo.bar/httpconf

Comment: @lukasz1985 1. hundreds of linux packages make directories with names like "init.d", furthermore it's not safe to rely on the path not having directories with dots, since it's not illegal
2. I was coding for Android so I used some SDK method I don't remember but I guess http://stackoverflow.com/a/3571239/2546146 doesn't have this flaw

Comment: @luke1985 all GitHub's repos are finishing with .git but they actually are folders :)

Comment: @Iman Akbari: getName() only returns the file name itself, which would be "httpconf" in your example.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on exceptions to guard against sloppy coding. Exception handling isn't required here.

Comment: [The edit which added `+ 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21974043/4) inadvertently introduced an incorrect behavior when the file name has no extension. In a case like `"abc"` the method is supposed to return `""` but the edit made it incorrectly return `"abc"`. I rolled the answer back to Ilya's revision because it's the best example code and the answer's original author (who prefers exceptions for some reason) is inactive.

Answer (score 88):

If you use **[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)** library, you can resort to [`Files`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html) utility class. It has a specific method, [`getFileExtension()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getFileExtension%28java.lang.String%29). For instance:

```
String path = "c:/path/to/file/foo.txt";
String ext = Files.getFileExtension(path);
System.out.println(ext); //prints txt
```

In addition you may also obtain the filename with a similar function, [getNameWithoutExtension()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getNameWithoutExtension(java.lang.String)):

```
String filename = Files.getNameWithoutExtension(path);
System.out.println(filename); //prints foo
```

Comment: Really? It is a great library, full of utilities. Most of them will be part of Java8, like the great Guava [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html).

Comment: Not all people can decide which libraries to use, unfortunately. At least we have Apache Commons, albeit an old one.

Comment: if you see the source code of `getFileExtension` actually it is just `int dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    return (dotIndex == -1) ? "" : fileName.substring(dotIndex + 1)` so not big deal. also, note that `Files` marked as "unstable" for some reason.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar a lot of classes are marked as unstable (see multimap builders), I also don't understand why: several released have been made, but nothing has been changed there.

Answer (score 27):

If on Android, you can use this:

```
String ext = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if the string is not encoded(e.g. contains a space or a chinese character), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14321470/1074998

Comment: it is not getting extension other than English language

Answer (score 20):

If you use Spring framework in your project, then you can use [StringUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html)

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

StringUtils.getFilenameExtension("YourFileName")
```

Answer (score 19):

This is a tested method

```
public static String getExtension(String fileName) {
    char ch;
    int len;
    if(fileName==null || 
            (len = fileName.length())==0 || 
            (ch = fileName.charAt(len-1))=='/' || ch=='\\' || //in the case of a directory
             ch=='.' ) //in the case of . or ..
        return "";
    int dotInd = fileName.lastIndexOf('.'),
        sepInd = Math.max(fileName.lastIndexOf('/'), fileName.lastIndexOf('\\'));
    if( dotInd<=sepInd )
        return "";
    else
        return fileName.substring(dotInd+1).toLowerCase();
}
```

And test case:

```
@Test
public void testGetExtension() {
    assertEquals("", getExtension("C"));
    assertEquals("ext", getExtension("C.ext"));
    assertEquals("ext", getExtension("A/B/C.ext"));
    assertEquals("", getExtension("A/B/C.ext/"));
    assertEquals("", getExtension("A/B/C.ext/.."));
    assertEquals("bin", getExtension("A/B/C.bin"));
    assertEquals("hidden", getExtension(".hidden"));
    assertEquals("dsstore", getExtension("/user/home/.dsstore"));
    assertEquals("", getExtension(".strange."));
    assertEquals("3", getExtension("1.2.3"));
    assertEquals("exe", getExtension("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\java\\bin\\javaw.exe"));
}
```

Answer (score 16):

In order to take into account file names without characters *before* the dot, you have to use that slight variation of the accepted answer:

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i >= 0) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```

---

```
"file.doc" => "doc"
"file.doc.gz" => "gz"
".doc" => "doc"
```

Comment: probably should defend itself against "foo." input.

Answer (score 16):

```
String path = "/Users/test/test.txt";
String extension = "";

if (path.contains("."))
     extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."));
```

return ".txt"

if you want only "txt", make `path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1`

Comment: This is one of the few answers that eliminates confusion as to what it's returning.

Answer (score 12):

My dirty and may tiniest using [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
.replaceAll("^.*\\.(.*)$", "$1")
```

Note that first `*` is greedy so it will grab most possible characters as far as it can and then just last dot and file extension will be left.

Comment: This fails if the file has no extension.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, still however can be used for simple scenarios like quick file type detection and such as having an incorrect extension isn't very different from having none, or one can put an if condition when result of replace equals with input.

Comment: Or even shorter `.replaceAll(".*\\.", "")`

Answer (score 10):

As is obvious from all the other answers, there's no adequate "built-in" function. This is a safe and simple method.

```
String getFileExtension(File file) {
    if (file == null) {
        return "";
    }
    String name = file.getName();
    int i = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    String ext = i > 0 ? name.substring(i + 1) : "";
    return ext;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is another one-liner for Java 8.

```
String ext = Arrays.stream(fileName.split("\\.")).reduce((a,b) -> b).orElse(null)
```

It works as follows:

1. Split the string into an array of strings using "."
2. Convert the array into a stream
3. Use reduce to get the last element of the stream, i.e. the file extension

Answer (score 9):

#### Java 20 EA

As of Java 20 EA (early-access), there is finally a new method [`Path#getExtension`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#getExtension()) that returns the extension as a `String`:

```java
Paths.get("/Users/admin/notes.txt").getExtension();              // "txt"
Paths.get("/Users/admin/.gitconfig").getExtension();             // "gitconfig"
Paths.get("/Users/admin/configuration.xml.zip").getExtension();  // "zip"
Paths.get("/Users/admin/file").getExtension();                   // null
```

Comment: Actually this seems to have been bumped from 20 and moved to 21 potentially: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8298303

Comment: @MrFlick Interesting... but I don't understand why they decided to remove it from 20 if it was impactless and already there.

Comment: If you follow some of the threads you can there was disagreement as to what the return value should be. They took extra time to work out the details which meant they missed the deadline for 20. It looks like the version included in 21 will include the dot in the extension name.

Comment: The function did not make it into 21. A new attempt is in progress: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8298318

Answer (score 8):

How about (using Java 1.5 RegEx):

```
    String[] split = fullFileName.split("\\.");
    String ext = split[split.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 8):

If you plan to use Apache commons-io,and just want to check the file's extension and then do some operation,you can use [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#isExtension%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29),here is a snippet:

```
if(FilenameUtils.isExtension(file.getName(),"java")) {
    someoperation();
}
```

Comment: Note that this check is case sensitive according to the docs.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Modified from EboMike's answer

String extension = "/path/to/file/foo.txt".substring("/path/to/file/foo.txt".lastIndexOf('.'));
```

extension should have ".txt" in it when run.

Comment: Will crash if the name doesn't have an extension.

Answer (score 4):

How about JFileChooser? It is not straightforward as you will need to parse its final output...

```
JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
File file = new File("your.txt");
System.out.println("the extension type:"+filechooser.getTypeDescription(file));
```

which is a MIME type...

OK...I forget that you don't want to know its MIME type.

Interesting code in the following link:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

```
/*
 * Get the extension of a file.
 */  
public static String getExtension(File f) {
    String ext = null;
    String s = f.getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (i > 0 &&  i < s.length() - 1) {
        ext = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return ext;
}
```

Related question:
[How do I trim a file extension from a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method that handles `.tar.gz` properly, even in a path with dots in directory names:

```
private static final String getExtension(final String filename) {
  if (filename == null) return null;
  final String afterLastSlash = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  final int afterLastBackslash = afterLastSlash.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
  final int dotIndex = afterLastSlash.indexOf('.', afterLastBackslash);
  return (dotIndex == -1) ? "" : afterLastSlash.substring(dotIndex + 1);
}
```

`afterLastSlash` is created to make finding `afterLastBackslash` quicker since it won't have to search the whole string if there are some slashes in it.

The `char[]` inside the original `String` is reused, adding no garbage there, and [the JVM will probably notice that `afterLastSlash` is immediately garbage in order to put it on the stack instead of the heap](http://web.archive.org/web/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html#2.0).

Comment: this method is copied from Guava source code you must mention this.

Comment: I didn't copy this. If it's in the Guava source code, they copied it from here. Perhaps notify them.

Comment: sorry for that it's not identical btw, so may you and the Guava dev just has the same idea.

Comment: Really "gz" is the correct extension to return. If the calling code can also handle "tar" then it should additionally check, external to a `getExtension` function. If the user's file name is `"my zip. don't touch.tar.gz"` then this method will return the wrong extension.

Answer (score 4):

This particular question gave me a lot of trouble then i found a very simple solution for this problem which i'm posting here.

```
file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
```

That's it.

Comment: OP Needs a way to extract extension - not to test for one.

Comment: actually whatever you are developing in most of the case you need to deal with a particular type of files only..so if your problem comes in this area this will help you.

Comment: Which doesn't address his requirements

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but this indeed was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

How about **REGEX** version:

```
static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\.(.*)");

Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(path);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("File path/name: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Extention: " + m.group(2));
}
```

or with null extension supported:

```
static final Pattern PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("((.*\\" + File.separator + ")?(.*)(\\.(.*)))|(.*\\" + File.separator + ")?(.*)");

class Separated {
    String path, name, ext;
}

Separated parsePath(String path) {
    Separated res = new Separated();
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(path);
    if (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            res.path = m.group(2);
            res.name = m.group(3);
            res.ext = m.group(5);
        } else {
            res.path = m.group(6);
            res.name = m.group(7);
        }
    }
    return res;
}


Separated sp = parsePath("/root/docs/readme.txt");
System.out.println("path: " + sp.path);
System.out.println("name: " + sp.name);
System.out.println("Extention: " + sp.ext);
```

result for *nix:
*path: /root/docs/

name: readme

Extention: txt*

for windows, parsePath("c:\windows\readme.txt"):
*path: c:\windows\

name: readme

Extention: txt*

Answer (score 2):

```
String extension = com.google.common.io.Files.getFileExtension("fileName.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the version with Optional as a return value (cause you can't be sure the file has an extension)... also sanity checks...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Optional;

public class GetFileExtensionTool {

    public static Optional<String> getFileExtension(File file) {
        if (file == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("file argument was null");
        }
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("getFileExtension(File file)"
                    + " called on File object that wasn't an actual file"
                    + " (perhaps a directory or device?). file had path: "
                    + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        String fileName = file.getName();
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0) {
            return Optional.of(fileName.substring(i + 1));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I made a small method (however not that secure and doesnt check for many errors), but if it is only you that is programming a general java-program, this is more than enough to find the filetype. This is not working for complex filetypes, but those are normally not used as much.

```
    public static String getFileType(String path){
       String fileType = null;
       fileType = path.substring(path.indexOf('.',path.lastIndexOf('/'))+1).toUpperCase();
       return fileType;
}
```

Comment: OP is looking for built-in method

Comment: (1) You should use `lastIndexOf` so file names like `john.smith.report.doc` are treated properly. (2) You should properly handle cases when there is no extension. This method returns `ABC/XYZ` for a path like `abc/xyz`, which doesn't make any sense. It would make more sense to return `""` or `null`. (3) [The file separator is not always `/`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar)

Answer (score 1):

Getting File Extension from File Name

```
/**
 * The extension separator character.
 */
private static final char EXTENSION_SEPARATOR = '.';

/**
 * The Unix separator character.
 */
private static final char UNIX_SEPARATOR = '/';

/**
 * The Windows separator character.
 */
private static final char WINDOWS_SEPARATOR = '\\';

/**
 * The system separator character.
 */
private static final char SYSTEM_SEPARATOR = File.separatorChar;

/**
 * Gets the extension of a filename.
 * <p>
 * This method returns the textual part of the filename after the last dot.
 * There must be no directory separator after the dot.
 * <pre>
 * foo.txt      --> "txt"
 * a/b/c.jpg    --> "jpg"
 * a/b.txt/c    --> ""
 * a/b/c        --> ""
 * </pre>
 * <p>
 * The output will be the same irrespective of the machine that the code is running on.
 *
 * @param filename the filename to retrieve the extension of.
 * @return the extension of the file or an empty string if none exists.
 */
public static String getExtension(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int index = indexOfExtension(filename);
    if (index == -1) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return filename.substring(index + 1);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the last extension separator character, which is a dot.
 * <p>
 * This method also checks that there is no directory separator after the last dot.
 * To do this it uses {@link #indexOfLastSeparator(String)} which will
 * handle a file in either Unix or Windows format.
 * <p>
 * The output will be the same irrespective of the machine that the code is running on.
 *
 * @param filename  the filename to find the last path separator in, null returns -1
 * @return the index of the last separator character, or -1 if there
 * is no such character
 */
public static int indexOfExtension(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int extensionPos = filename.lastIndexOf(EXTENSION_SEPARATOR);
    int lastSeparator = indexOfLastSeparator(filename);
    return (lastSeparator > extensionPos ? -1 : extensionPos);
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the last directory separator character.
 * <p>
 * This method will handle a file in either Unix or Windows format.
 * The position of the last forward or backslash is returned.
 * <p>
 * The output will be the same irrespective of the machine that the code is running on.
 *
 * @param filename  the filename to find the last path separator in, null returns -1
 * @return the index of the last separator character, or -1 if there
 * is no such character
 */
public static int indexOfLastSeparator(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int lastUnixPos = filename.lastIndexOf(UNIX_SEPARATOR);
    int lastWindowsPos = filename.lastIndexOf(WINDOWS_SEPARATOR);
    return Math.max(lastUnixPos, lastWindowsPos);
}
```

**Credits**

1. Copied from Apache FileNameUtils Class - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.java#FilenameUtils.getExtension%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

Without use of any library, you can use the String method split as follows :

```
        String[] splits = fileNames.get(i).split("\\.");

        String extension = "";

        if(splits.length >= 2)
        {
            extension = splits[splits.length-1];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private String getExtension(File file)
        {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            String[] ext = fileName.split("\\.");
            return ext[ext.length -1];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a regular-expression based alternative. Not that fast, not that good.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.([^.]*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String ext = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the simplicity of [spectre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21974043/2089760), and linked in one of his comments is a link to another answer that fixes dots in file paths, on another question, [made by EboMike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571239/2089760).

Without implementing some sort of third party API, I suggest:

```
private String getFileExtension(File file) {

    String name = file.getName().substring(Math.max(file.getName().lastIndexOf('/'),
            file.getName().lastIndexOf('\\')) < 0 ? 0 : Math.max(file.getName().lastIndexOf('/'),
            file.getName().lastIndexOf('\\')));
    int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (lastIndexOf == -1) {
        return ""; // empty extension
    }
    return name.substring(lastIndexOf + 1); // doesn't return "." with extension
}
```

Something like this may be useful in, say, [any of ImageIO's `write` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)), where the file format has to be passed in.

Why use a whole third party API when you can DIY?

Answer (score 0):

The fluent way:

> ```
> public static String fileExtension(String fileName) {
>     return Optional.of(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")).filter(i-> i >= 0)
>             .filter(i-> i > fileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator))
>             .map(fileName::substring).orElse("");
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
String[] extension = "adadad.adad.adnandad.jpg".split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)"); // ['adadad.adad.adnandad','jpg']
extension[1] // jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  @Test
    public void getFileExtension(String fileName){
      String extension = null;
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      do{
          extension =  FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
          if(extension==null){
              break;
          }
          if(!extension.isEmpty()){
              list.add("."+extension);
          }
          fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName);
      }while (!extension.isEmpty());
      Collections.reverse(list);
      System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a better way to find extension by mixing all above answers

```
public static String getFileExtension(String fileLink) {

        String extension;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileLink);
        String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        if (scheme != null && scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(CoreApp.getInstance().getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        } else {
            extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileLink);
        }

        return extension;
    }

public static String getMimeType(String fileLink) {
        String type = CoreApp.getInstance().getContentResolver().getType(Uri.parse(fileLink));
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(type)) return type;
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(FileChooserUtil.getFileExtension(fileLink));
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Java has a built-in way of dealing with this, in the [java.nio.file.Files class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29), that may work for your needs:

```
File f = new File("/path/to/file/foo.txt");
String ext = Files.probeContentType(f.toPath());
if(ext.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) do whatever;
```

Note that this static method uses the specifications [found here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) to retrieve "content type," which can vary.

Comment: This is incorrect. The return type for probeContentType is the Mime content type, not the file extension. It will usually not match the extension. This would also be pretty slow in a file browser, since it actually opens the file to determine the type.