# JAI error when uploading PNG and GIF files

Tags: java, gxt, jai

I am new to using JAI and I wrote this simple code to upload images. This code works fine for `jpeg`s but causes error for `png`s and `gif`s.

Here is the code:

```
ByteArraySeekableStream byteArraySeekableStream = new ByteArraySeekableStream(content.getData());
ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
pb.add(byteArraySeekableStream);
BufferedImage originalImage = JAI.create("jpeg", pb).getAsBufferedImage();
```

This is the error:

```
    Error: Cannot decode the image for the type :
Occurs in: com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil
java.io.IOException
        at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.CodecUtils.toIOException(CodecUtils.java:76)
        at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:48)
        at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:88)
        at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.JPEGRIF.create(JPEGRIF.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
        at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
        at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
        at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getColorModel(RenderedOp.java:2242)
        at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2498)
        at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2546)
```

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Try changing `BufferedImage originalImage = JAI.create("jpeg", pb).getAsBufferedImage();` to `BufferedImage originalImage = JAI.create("png", pb).getAsBufferedImage();` for `png` and `gif` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the correct file type to the `BufferedImage` and it should work.

**PNG**
`BufferedImage originalImage = JAI.create("png", pb).getAsBufferedImage();`

**GIF**
`BufferedImage originalImage = JAI.create("gif", pb).getAsBufferedImage();`

And have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java) to get the file extensions.