# How to check the extension of a Java 7 Path

Tags: java, path, java-7

I'd like to check if a [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) (introduced in Java 7) ends with a  certain extension. I tried the `endsWith()` method like so:

```
Path path = Paths.get("foo/bar.java")
if (path.endsWith(".java")){
    //Do stuff
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work because `path.endsWith(".java")` returns false. It seems the `endsWith()` method only returns true if there is a complete match for everything after the final directory separator (e.g. `bar.java`), which isn't practical for me.

So how can I check the file extension of a Path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: @assylias, that question is for finding the extension from a `String`, not a `Path` (although it would work with `Path.toString()`, but I was hoping for a way that wouldn't require that).

Comment: The notion of file extension is os dependent so I don't think there is support for it in File or Path.

Comment: @assylias: Well, that sucks. The notion of file extension is well-defined and used many times in Windows/Linux/MacOs/Android. Even though they might be less important in Linux than in Windows, they are still very much used on desktop and server applications.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Java NIO's [PathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html) provides [FileSystem.getPathMatcher(String syntaxAndPattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-):

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.java");

Path filename = ...;
if (matcher.matches(filename.getFileName())) {
    System.out.println(filename);
}
```

`.getFileName()` is required when your path contains more than one component.

See the [Finding Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) tutorial for details.

Comment: I think this is missing an asterisk, the following works for me: `PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.java");`

Comment: And if you're looking through different directories, you need to use "glob:**.java"

Comment: For me LaGrandMere's comment did the trick. If @Dave Jarvis could merge his advise into the elected answer, I guess that would help beginners in the NIO-API. Under Windoze: If I do want to use `glob:*.java`, then `filename` should not contain any parent-path. If I use a rel/abs path like `glob:c:/users/muchwow/*.java`, it works (note that \\\\ has to be used with backslashes). The pattern `glob:**.java` just searches for everything with *.java in it, regardless of the parent path.

Comment: Throwing a PathMatcher onto this problem is quite an expensive hammer, compared to just checking whether the filename (string) ends with a suffix.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36954357/10663941

Answer (score 79):

The `Path` class does not have a notion of "extension", probably because the file system itself does not have it. Which is why you need to check its `String` representation and see if it ends with the <strike>four</strike> *five* character string `.java`. Note that you need a different comparison than simple `endsWith` if you want to cover mixed case, such as `".JAVA"` and `".Java"`:

```
path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java");
```

Comment: This is not good solution because of possible NullPointer. It is better to use some library (e.g. apache IO utils) or PathMatcher as mentioned above.

Answer (score 24):

Simple solution:

```
if( path.toString().endsWith(".java") ) //Do something
```

You have to be carefull, when using the Path.endsWith method. As you stated, the method will return **true** only if it matches with a subelement of your Path object. 
For example:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:/Users/Public/Mycode/HelloWorld.java");
System.out.println(p.endsWith(".java")); // false
System.out.println(p.endsWith("HelloWorld.java")); // true
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this directly on the Path object itself.

There are two options I can see:

1. Convert the Path to a File and call endsWith on the String returned by File.getName()
2. Call toString on the Path and call endsWith on that String.

Comment: I like the first option.