# In Scala find files that match a wildcard String

Tags: file, scala, wildcard, scala-collections

How to obtain an `Array[io.BufferedSource]` to all files that match a wildcard in a given directory ?

Namely, how to define a method `io.Source.fromDir` such that

```
val txtFiles: Array[io.BufferedSource] = io.Source.fromDir("myDir/*.txt") // ???
```

Noticed [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), yet much preferred is a Scala API based approach without external dependencies.

Comment: Close to a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637643/how-do-i-list-all-files-in-a-subdirectory-in-scala (you'd need to create the BufferedSource for each file, but that's a trivial extension)

Comment: Perhaps a difference here are the wildcards interpretation, could not find a Scala-based answer on that respect.

Comment: Probably isn't too difficult to translate a glob to a regexp (`*` -> `[^/]*`, `?` -> `.`, `.` -> `\.`)?

Comment: And of course, that question's already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
scala> import reflect.io._, Path._
import reflect.io._
import Path._

scala> val r = """.*\.scala""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*\.scala

scala> "/home/amarki/tmp".toDirectory.files map (_.name) flatMap { case n @ r() => Some(n) case _ => None }
res0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> .toList
res1: List[String] = List(bobsrandom.scala, ...)
```

or recursing

```
scala> import PartialFunction.{ cond => when }
import PartialFunction.{cond=>when}

scala> "/home/amarki/tmp" walkFilter (p => p.isDirectory || when(p.name) {
     | case r() => true })
res3: Iterator[scala.reflect.io.Path] = non-empty iterator
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an answer based on [this great answer from @som-snytt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556308/5741205):

```
scala> import reflect.io._, Path._
import reflect.io._
import Path._

scala> "/temp".toDirectory.files.map(_.path).filter(name => name matches """.*\.xlsx""")
res2: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

as an Array:

```
scala> "/temp".toDirectory.files.map(_.path).filter(name => name matches """.*\.xlsx""").toArray
res3: Array[String] = Array(/temp/1.xlsx, /temp/2.xlsx, /temp/3.xlsx, /temp/a.1.xlsx, /temp/Book1.xlsx, /temp/new.xlsx)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8, it is possible to traverse a directory and all it's subdirectories. 
Then convert the iterator to scala, and then filter according to files ending with .txt:

`import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
java.nio.file.Files.walk(Paths.get("mydir")).iterator().asScala.filter(file => file.toString.endsWith(".txt")).foreach(println)`

Comment: Thanks for this, although I couldn't get `.filter(file => file.endsWith(".txt"))` to work. I had success with declaring a `PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.txt")` and then `.filter(matcher.matches)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25188854

Comment: @dmarwick, you are correct.
I forgot to add a `toString`. Corrected the answer.
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

A bit rough on the edges, but maybe something like :

```
def getFilesMatchingRegex(dir: String, regex: util.matching.Regex) = {
    new java.io.File(dir).listFiles
        .filter(file => regex.findFirstIn(file.getName).isDefined)
        .map   (file => io.Source.fromFile(file))
}
```

Note that this won't fetch files in sub-directories, doesn't have more advance globbing features one might expect (à la `ls ./**/*.scala`), etc…

Comment: `dir.listFiles map (_.getPath) collect { case f @ r() => io.Source.fromFile(f) }`