# Glob pattern using getPathMatcher

Tags: java, path, glob

From the book of "Kathy Sierra Bert Bates" for OCP exam I found the following code

```
public class FileTest {

    public static void matches(Path path, String glob){
        PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
        System.out.println(matcher.matches(path));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("/com/java/One.java");
        matches(path, "glob:*.java");
        matches(path, "glob:**/*.java");
        matches(path, "glob:*");
        matches(path, "glob:**");

    }
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
false
true
```

I can not understand the output clearly. Would any one explain me. let me know my example what is crossing directory boundaries.
Thanks
Rocky

Comment: I don't get the output that you have provided for the input path. But i get your output when i just pass the file name - `Paths.get("One.java")`. On windows, NTFS file system. Which OS and which file system you tested this code on?

Comment: @BatScream the code is working for me as it is in windows OS, and I get the same result as mentioned by the OP

Answer (score 4):

```
matches(path, "glob:*.java"); // => flase
```

because your path contains `/` which describe a directory hierarchy, `*.java` matches any file name with `.java` extension

```
matches(path, "glob:**/*.java"); // => true
```

because `**` matches any string, including sub-path (like `/com/java/` in you example)

```
matches(path, "glob:*"); // => false
```

as mentioned in the first one, because you have path separator `/`

```
matches(path, "glob:**"); // => true
```

as mentioned in the second one, because `**` matches any string including `/`

Comment: the "matches(path, "glob:**/*.java");" works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FileTest {

    public static void matches(Path path, String glob){
        PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
        System.out.println(matcher.matches(path));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("/com/java/One.java");
        matches(path, "glob:*.java");       // regular expression that matches any file path that end with .java so it will return the value as true
        matches(path, "glob:**/*.java"); // regular expression ** characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory boundaries so it will match complete path but if you put /* it will search for a path like this /com/java//one.java soe here it will not match the path and will return value as false.
        matches(path, "glob:*"); // this will match any path and return value as true.
        matches(path, "glob:**"); // this will complete path crossing directory so it will return you value as true.

    }
}
```

In the above program when you are calling matches with the path as `"/com/java/One.java"` and glob regular expression for searching or matching the path the function will take the values and perform the operation and return true or false.
Output:

```
true
false
true
true
```

If you are using the windows platform then you need to modify your program as follows.

```
public class match {

  public static void matches(Path path, String glob){
    PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches(path));
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("\\com\\java\\One.java");
    matches(path, "glob:*.java");
    matches(path, "glob:**\\*.java");
    matches(path, "glob:*");
    matches(path, "glob:**");

  }
}
```

For more details [Click here](http://java.boot.by/ocpjp7-upgrade/ch06s05.html)