# java stream filter not showing output

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

The following code displays files.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\pdf"))
                .map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().getFileName())
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But this dosen't display pdf output why it is not working ?

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\pdf"))
                .map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().getFileName())
                    .filter(path -> path.endsWith(".pdf"))
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531247/how-to-check-the-extension-of-a-java-7-path) points out and [this article](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.ch/2014/04/be-careful-with-java-pathendswithstring.html) explains, `path.endsWith()` only returns true if there is a complete match for everything after the final directory separator:

> If you need to compare the `java.io.file.Path` object, be aware that `Path.endsWith(String)` **will ONLY match another sub-element of Path object in your original path**, not the path name string portion! If you want to match the string name portion, you would need to call the `Path.toString()` first.

A quick fix is to replace the filter with:

```
path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
```

There is also Java NIO's [PathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html), which is made for dealing with paths. Here is an example:

```
final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.pdf");
```

You can use with:

```
.filter(path -> matcher.matches(path))
```

See [Finding Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) tutorial for more details.