# Searching Through a Directory

Tags: java, file, search, directory

Hello one of the parts of a program i'm working on requires the ability to search through a directory. I understand how using a path variable works and how to get to a directory; but once you are in the directory how can you distinguish files from one another? Can we make an array/or a linked list of the files contained within the directory and search using that?

In this specific program the goal is for the user to input a directory, from there go into sub-directory and find a file that ends with .mp3 and copy that to a new user created directory. It is certain that there will only be one .mp3 file in the folder.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted any part of this so far? It would be helpful if you posted your code. Do you want the user to do this through point-and-click UI, or by typing commands?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing what you say, I will suppose that you use the java7 Path api.

To know if a path is a directory or a simple file, use Files.isDirectory(Path)

To list the files / directories in your directory, use Files.list(Path)

The javadoc of the Files class : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

If you use the "old" java.io.File api, then you have a listFiles method, which can take a FileFilter as argument to filter, for exemple, only the files ending with ".mp3".

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `File` object to represent your directory, and then use the `listFiles()` (which return an array of files `File[]`) to retrieve the files into that directory.

If you need to search through subdirectories, you can use `listFiles()` recursively for each directory you encounter.

As for the file extension, the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library has a neat `FileFilter` for that: the `SuffixFileFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

Get Files as so:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
File[] files = new File("/path/to/the/directory").listFiles();
for (File file : files) 
    if (file.isFile()) 
        results.add(file.getName());
```

If you want the extension:

```
public static String getExtension(String filename){
    String extension = "";
    int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i > 0) 
        extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
    return extension;
}
```

There are other ways to get file extensions [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java) but they usually require a common external library.