# how to pick a file in SD card?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app with Android Studio that can select a file in SD card and get its path, like an `OpenFileDialog`, I've tried this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

However, it does not work, how can I do it ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30827530/3681880)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  mediaIntent.setType("*/*"); //set mime type as per requirement
  startActivityForResult(mediaIntent,0);
```

You can change type according to your need.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
       Log.d("", "Video URI= " + videoUri);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt recognize REQUESTCODE_PICK_VIDEO , what is it ?

Comment: im a beginner so could u go to more details please ?

Comment: I changed my answer. It is the value that you provide when called startActivityForResult(). It only used to recognize that result is for that same query.