# passing file name to intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new to android and trying to create an app which has a file picker and plays a particular file. I have been able to create the intent to open files; however I'm not able to pass the file path from the file picker to the intent to open that same particular file. Code given below. Appreciate any help. thanks.

***EDIT*** Adding lines I missed___

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
public String root = "/mnt/usbhost0";
public TextView myPath;


   @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
        getDir(root);
    }


    public void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (!dirPath.equals(root))
        {
            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            File file = files[i];
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if (file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            else
                item.add(file.getName());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

    File file;


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        File file = new File(path.get(position));
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if (file.canRead())
                getDir(path.get(position));
            else
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                                    @Override

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }

                                }).show();

            }

        } else

        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setTitle("Select")
                    .setMessage("Select " + file.getName() + " to play ?") //Send fileurl from here //
                    .setPositiveButton("Select", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            new DecryptTask().execute();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();


        }


    }

    void decrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        File videoFile2Play = new File(//to here);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile2Play), "video/m4v");
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public class DecryptTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                decrypt();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT*** July 27, 2018

Updated my code as per @miguelarc's suggestion, but still unable to pass the name. Any suggestions or mistakes pointed out?

---

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
public String root = "/mnt/usbhost0";
public TextView myPath;


@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
    getDir(root);
}


public void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];
        path.add(file.getPath());
        if (file.isDirectory())
            item.add(file.getName() + "/");
        else
            item.add(file.getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

File file;


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final File file = new File(path.get(position));
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if (file.canRead())
            getDir(path.get(position));
        else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                                @Override

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                            }).show();

        }

    } else

    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setTitle("Select")
                .setMessage("Select " + file.getName() + " to play ?")
                .setPositiveButton("Select", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        new DecryptTask(file.getAbsolutePath()).execute();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();


    }


}

void decrypt(String filePath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File videoFile2Play = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile2Play), "video/*");
    startActivity(i);
}


public class DecryptTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String filePath;

    public DecryptTask(String filePath){
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading your video");
        pd.show();

    }




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            decrypt(this.filePath);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You passed the variable "root" into a method in your onCreate(). Where did you declare and initialize root?

Comment: @Taslim sorry, missed my first few lines

Comment: Hope this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789116/implementing-a-file-picker-in-android-and-copying-the-selected-file-to-another-l) will might help you.

Comment: what the issue in @miguelarc's Solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `filePath` to your DecryptTask. Add a constructor to it, and add the filePath, so you can initialize your `videoFile2Play` with the valid path. At the moment, your file is not initializing anything, that's why the intent is not starting/showing anything.

Add a constructor like so:

```
public class DecryptTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String filePath;

    public DecryptTask(String filePath){
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            decrypt(this.filePath); //<--- Add filePath as param of decrypt method
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

then, use the filePath you got inside the `decrypt()` method.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, I've updated my question with the updated code. any help is appreciated. thanks @miguelarc

Comment: @Lavin_38 have you debugged it? What is the value of this.filePath in the decrypt() method called inside doInBackground() method?