# Unable to copy file to different location using file picker

Tags: android, android-file, filepicker

I am trying to implement a button for browsing the file and copying it to 'downloads' folder. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789116/implementing-a-file-picker-in-android-and-copying-the-selected-file-to-another-l) solution to do so. Please see my code here:

```
public void browseFile(View view) {

    Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    chooseFile.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file"),
            PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE
    );
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    File destination = null;
    File source = null;
    if (requestCode == PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri content_describer = data.getData();
        String src = content_describer.getPath();
        source = new File(src);
        Log.d("src is ", source.toString());
        String filename = content_describer.getLastPathSegment();
        //text.setText(filename);
        Log.d("FileName is ", filename);
        destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/GSW/" + filename);
        Log.d("Destination is ", destination.toString());
        //SetToFolder.setEnabled(true);
    }

    try {
        copy(source, destination);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using a copy function as mentioned in the solution to copy the file to destination folder as below:

```
private void copy(File src, File dest) throws IOException {

    FileChannel in = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();

    try {
        in.transferTo(0, in.size(), out);
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    }
}
```

I tried many other solutions given but I am still getting "FileNotFoundException" as below:

**Error**

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/IGN Holiday List 2020.pdf (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

**EDIT 1**

I updated my code as suggested by @blackapps Still getting FileNotFoundException but this time with the destination.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri content_describer = data.getData();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        // open the user-picked file for reading:
        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(content_describer);
        // open the output-file:
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/GSW/" + File.separator));
        // copy the content:
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        // Contents are copied!
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null){
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

2020-02-12 17:07:09.214 5412-5412/com.gsw.nfc W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/GSW (Is a directory)
2020-02-12 17:07:09.215 5412-5412/com.gsw.nfc W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)

Comment: Well isnt GWS a directory? I see no filename. You should have something like `/storage/emulated/0/Download/GSW/copiedfile.jpg` if you want to open a file output stream. You have `"/GSW/" + File.separator` hence two slashes at the end. There can not be a slash at the end if it is a file path.

Comment: And does GWS exist?

Comment: Yes, GSW does exist. filename was the issue. Once I added the filename it got solved !! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You treat the data as a file and use a FileInputStream for a path that does not exist.

Use an InputStream instread.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

Then use `is` like you used `fis`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and I am getting error now on destination file.

Comment: You should only apply this for the input file.