# Checking type of a file (csv or excel file(xlsx)) in java

Tags: java, excel, csv

I need to upload a file. Before I upload it, I need to know if the file is either csv or excel file(xlsx). If it is csv or excel file I will continue else exit.
How can I know the type of a file in java by using its path.

Comment: This link gives you so many answers choose the best. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: `if( filename.endsWith(".xlsx")) { ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`probeContentType(Path path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) for this.

> Probes the content type of a file.

If the `content-type` is `text/csv` it is a `.csv` file. If the `content-type` is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` it is a `.xlsx` file.

You should try something like:

```
File file = new File("some path");
Path filePath = file.toPath();
String contentType = probeContentType(filePath);
if("text/csv".equals(contentType)) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: this method is very buggy and java flavour dependent on what it recognises

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?php
  $mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
    if(in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$mimes)){
      // do something
    } else {
      die("Sorry, mime type not allowed");
    }

?>
```