# How to get the file extension in Android?

Tags: android, file-extension

I am a newbie.
I have an EditText and a Browse Button to explore Folders and select files only.
From the Browse Button, when a file is clicked it stores the folder path in which that file is in one string and the file name without extension in other string, which I am using to store, either of these two, in the EditText.

I want to make the file name with the exactly file extension (whether one or two dots), but I don't have any idea how to get the file extension also.

All answers will be appreciated.
**FileChooser.java**

```
    package com.threefriends.filecrypto;

/**
 * Created by hp on 01-06-2016.
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView; 

public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {

    private File currentDir;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        currentDir=new File("/sdcard/");
        fill(currentDir); 
    }
    private void fill(File f)
    {
        File[]dirs=f.listFiles();
        this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
        List<Item>dir=new ArrayList<Item>();
        List<Item>fls=new ArrayList<Item>();
        try{
             for(File ff: dirs)
             { 
                Date lastModDate=new Date(ff.lastModified());
                DateFormat formater=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify=formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()){


                    File[] fbuf=ff.listFiles();
                    int buf=0;
                    if(fbuf != null){ 
                        buf=fbuf.length;
                    } 
                    else
                        buf=0;
                    String num_item=String.valueOf(buf);
                    if(buf == 0)
                        num_item=num_item+" item";
                    else
                        num_item = num_item+" items";

                    //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(), num_item, date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon"));
                }
                else
                {
                    fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(), ff.length()+" Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "file_icon"));
                }
             }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        Collections.sort(dir);
        Collections.sort(fls);
        dir.addAll(fls);
        if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
            dir.add(0, new Item("..", "Parent Directory", "", f.getParent(), "directory_up"));
        adapter=new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this, R.layout.file_view, dir);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Item o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon") || o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up")){
                currentDir=new File(o.getPath());
                fill(currentDir);
        }
        else
        {
            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }
    private void onFileClick(Item o)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Clicked: "+ currentDir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("GetPath", currentDir.toString());
        intent.putExtra("GetFileName", o.getName());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Part of **MainActivity.java**

```
//Defined for file edittext.
    EditText editText2;
 private static String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName(); //For File Exploring.
    private static final int REQUEST_PATH = 1;
    String curFileName;
    String filePath;
    EditText edittext;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);  //Done for File Exploring, EditText, Browse Button.
        Button b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.skipButton);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), FileChooser.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_PATH);
            }
        }
        );
}
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // See which child activity is calling us back.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PATH)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                curFileName = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName");
                filePath=data.getStringExtra("GetPath");
                edittext.setText(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code where you "explore Folders and select files only".

Comment: Yes, I have editted it. There are some more files for File Explorer, those are for logic, these two I have editted, are the main files. Tell if those also needed. File's parent path is storing in filePath and File name storing in curFileName.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 91, accepted):

lots of ways . here are 2 sample-

```
String someFilepath = "image.fromyesterday.test.jpg"; 
String extension = someFilepath.substring(someFilepath.lastIndexOf("."));
```

So in you case, it should be something like that

```
String extension = ff.getAbsolutePath().substring(ff.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
```

In case if you don't want to do it yourself-

use [FilenameUtils.getExtension](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)-

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/path/to/file/mytext.txt");
```

or in your case -

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(ff.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: FilenameUtils is undefined in ANdroid

Comment: @HiteshSahu, it is part of Apache Commins IO mentioned in the answer.

Comment: what will it return `txt` or `.txt`?

Comment: should return "txt" . @DakshAgrawal

Comment: @AmitK.Saha the first example returns ".txt"

Comment: If you want to return file extension without `.`, use `lastIndexOf(".") + 1`

Answer (score 33):

You could just do it with one line of code using MIME Type Map.

First grab the file:

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
```

Then

```
String fileExt = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.toString());
```

Comment: Best and simple built in solution. This is actual way to find the extension.

Comment: This get nothing if having space before "." in name of file

Comment: How important is it to grab the file first? Is there any harm in just passing in the filename string?

Comment: @AnandSavjani not working for "/storage/emulated/0/Download/download (1).jpeg" "/storage/emulated/0/Download/download (1) .jpeg"

Comment: Do not use this. This does not work if file name has special characters in it.

Comment: MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl only works with english characters (there is  pattern "[a-zA-Z_0-9\\.\\-\\(\\)\\%]+" inside), so unicode filenames will not proceed

Answer (score 18):

You can put your code in your activity like this:

```
    private String getfileExtension(Uri uri)
        {
            String extension;
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            extension= mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri)); 
            return extension;
        }
```

"uri" is the file uri from the result of "Browse button" selected file

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin Approach:

```
val fileExtention: String = file.extension
```

Check this: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/extension.html

Answer (score 4):

Function:

```
public String getExt(String filePath){
        int strLength = filePath.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(strLength > 0)
            return filePath.substring(strLength + 1).toLowerCase();
        return null;
    }
```

Usage:

```
String ext = getExt(path);
if(ext != null && ext.equals("txt")){
    // do anything
}
```

PS: If you don't use toLowerCase(), possible the function returns upper and lower cases (dependent the exists file).

Answer (score 4):

### In Kotlin

You can read the MimeTypeMap documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap#getExtensionFromMimeType(java.lang.String))

This is example if you are using `startActivityForResult` and you get data from it. Then you define `Content Resolver` to get mime type from the uri.

```
val uri: Uri? = it.data?.data
val contentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver
val stringMimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri!!)
```

Using that code, if you choose pdf file you will get something like

> "application/pdf"

After that, using the `MimeTypeMap` you'll get the extensions. Don't forget that you should add `getSingleton()` because it's only available in singleton.

```
val stringFileType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(stringMimeType)
```

Answer (score 2):

I used DocumentFile to get the file name and extension

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(YourActivity.this, fileUri);

String fileName = documentFile.getName();
String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
```

For example, if your file name is 'your_image.jpg' then the extension will be '.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

In Java

```
public String getFileExt(String fileName) {
    return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
  }
```

In Kotlin

```
 fun getFileExt(fileName: String): String? {
    return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

```
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap    

MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl("my.xlsx") // xlsx
MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl("my.pdf") // pdf
MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl("http://www.google.com/my.docx") // docx
MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(File.createTempFile("aaa", ".txt").absolutePath) // txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting extension of file in Kotlin:

```
 fun getExtension(fileName: String): String {
                return fileName.substring(if (fileName.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) fileName
                    .lastIndexOf(".") + 1 else return "",fileName.length)
            }
```

Comment: In kotlin, one can use `File.extension` to get the extension of the file, no need of writing this. Read more here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/extension.html

Answer (score 0):

```
getContentResolver().getType(theReceivedUri); // return  "media/format"
```