# Talend - Exclude files withe a specific mask

Tags: java, regex, etl, talend

I recover from a FTP server, flat files which has these names:

- abc
- abc.flag
- abc.tmp
- test
- test.flag
- test.tmp

In my case, I have to recover just the files: **abc** and **test**.
I tried with the following mask but it did not work: **"(.+\.tmp)| (. + \.flag) "**
is there another way to do this ?

Comment: why not to use (abc)|(test) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find of an expression that would select all but .tmp and .flag files, but here's an [example](https://regex101.com/r/zE9cB5/1) to select them, which uses `.+(?:flag|tmp)$`.

**Updated**

Assuming negative lookaheads are allowed, see this [example](https://regex101.com/r/zE9cB5/2) that only selects non .tmp and .flag files, which uses

`^.+\.(?!flag|tmp).+$|^\w+$`

Comment: No, I want to exclude just the files that have the extension .tmp and .flag

Comment: Updated my answer, presuming you can match those with .flag and .tmp and exclude them yourself.
Have you also considered [getting the file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java) and filtering those that you dont want?

Comment: No, saw that in TalendOS there is a tFTPListe that I give just the masck of files I want to recover, this masck is in regex

Comment: This mask is working fine now
`"[abc]"+"+([^.flag]|[^.tmp])"`
I get file abc that don't have extension .flag or .tmp

Comment: Updated my answer again, this time with an expression that selects the file you want. Looking at the one you commented, `[^.flag]`, means you dont want any files that has a `.`, `f`, `a` or `g`. In other words, if the file extension is `.glaf`, it wouldnt be selected as well. Same situation goes to `[^.tmp]`. Are you sure that is what you need?

Comment: You are right, I changed my mask to `"abc"+"+(?!flag|tmp)"` Because I want to get juste file **abc** not **abc.flag**, **def** or **def.flag** for that I fixed the value abc