# Trying to extract user input and return file extension

Tags: java, output

So i'm trying to take user input that has a extension like .txt or .html but I'm not sure if you can do String slicing in Java like you can in Python. Could I please get some help? I'm trying to understand the concept and not just get an easy answer.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileReader {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a file name and its extension!");
    String fileName = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println(fileName);
    String[] parts = fileName.split("");
    String ext = parts[0];

  }

  /* ADD YOUR CODE HERE */

}
```

Comment: Dupe: [How do I get the file extension of a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3571223)

Answer (score 2):

Try to split on the `.`:

```
String[] parts = fileName.split("\\.");
String ext = parts[1];  // the extension will be the second part
```

But it might better to test if there are two parts though using:

```
if (parts.length > 1) {
    ext = parts[1];
}
else {
    ext = "No extension";
}
```

If you like to support dots in the regular filename, then use this approach:

```
if (parts.length > 1) {
    ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
}
else {
    ext = "No extension";
}
```

Comment: No need to mention me ;P.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) along with [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)):

```
String fileName = keyboard.next();
int lastDotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
String ext = "":
if (lastDotIndex > 0) {
    ext = filename.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
}
```

If no extension be present, then this code snippet will return empty string.  Otherwise, it will return what it perceives to be the extension.

Here is another clever method using regular expressions:

```
String filename = "some.file.name.txt";
String ext = filename.indexOf(".") > 0 ? filename.replaceAll("^.*\\.(\\w+)$", "$1") : "";
```

The `.*` in the regex will greedily consume until hitting the final extension, if it be present, and it will retain only this final extension.  You can explore this regex here:

## Regex101

Comment: Please leave some feedback.  We use this method in production.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you might want to use existing libs like [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getFileExtension(java.lang.String)) or [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) to avoid re-inventing the wheel.