# Java : How to Check Directory contain only file

Tags: java, directory

i am trying to upload zip file which contains only csv file . 
now i have to validate before fetching file data that directory which i have extracted contains only csv file not any other child folder/directory which contains csv file ?

Comment: hmmm I think your best shot is to call `listFiles()` and then filter that array, you can be declarative using java streams(needs java 8) or you can do it in a for loop

Comment: `isDirectory` is for checking whether the `File` object is a directory or not, to get the extension you can use apache-commons IO, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: This can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder

You can then check for the files/directory in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming path is your String.

```
File file = new File(path);

boolean exists =      file.exists();      // Check if the file exists
boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory(); // Check if it's a directory
boolean isFile =      file.isFile();      // Check if it's a regular file
```

Or you can use the NIO class Files and check things like this:

```
Path file = new File(path).toPath();

boolean exists =      Files.exists(file);        // Check if the file exists
boolean isDirectory = Files.isDirectory(file);   // Check if it's a directory
boolean isFile =      Files.isRegularFile(file); // Check if it's a regular file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way:

```
File rootDir = new File("/my/path/to/exploded/zip/file");
boolean onlyFiles = Arrays.stream(rootDir.list())
                   .allMatch(filename -> new File(rootDir, filename).isFile());
```

But it only makes sure, all files below your `rootDir` are files and not directories. You may add another condition to check all files end with a given extension like `.csv`:

```
File rootDir = new File("/");
boolean onlyCsvFiles = Arrays.stream(rootDir.list())
                      .allMatch(filename -> new File(rootDir, filename).isFile() &&
                                            filename.endsWith(".csv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

using java 8 you can verify if any of the elements in a path is directory or not:
following implementation returns true if a folder is found in the path C:\Foo

```
String pathString = "C:\\Foo";
Path myPath = Paths.get(pathString);
boolean f = Files.list(myPath).anyMatch(x -> Files.isDirectory(x));
System.out.println(f);
```