# Regular expression to extract file name?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove last three character of filenames.  To rename any files, i'm using:

```
String str = ""; // Here set File name, i.e. listFile.getName();  
String[] tempFile = str.split("[$^txt]");
```

This regex remove last three character it's OK, but when passing any file name containing "t OR x" the regex remove it. For example:

```
1) fileName.txt   -> result after split -> fileName -> OK. 
2) textfile.txt   -> result after split -> efile. -> remove any t OR x in file name.
```

**My Q is : How i can remove only last three char.**

Thank you

Comment: `str.split(".txt$");`?

Comment: `[$^txt]` is a character class. It reads `$` _or_ `^` _or_ `t` _or_ `x` _or_ `t`. And it splits on any _one_ of those characters.

Comment: We're all assuming it's the file extension `.txt`.  Do you want to remove a file extension or do you really want to remove the last 3 characters.  So if a file name is `myNameIsBob` you will get `myNameIs` or do if the file name is `myNameIsBob.txt`, do you want `myNameIsBob`?

Comment: have you thought of using Apache Commons IO? it definitly fits your purpose -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: sometimes extensions can be longer than 3 characters too... excel.xlxs  do you really just want to dump the extensions?

Comment: do you want myNameIsBob? Yes, that what i need .

Comment: The last dot can be found with this regex: _Find_  `"\\.([^.]*)$"` replace `".<your extension"`. Any string methods like _lastIndexOf, find next/first_, etc.. is far too slow !!

Comment: use this:
str.split(".txt");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the file's extension a regex is much too complicated for the task. You can work with [String.lastIndexOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-) instead to determine the position of the file extension:

```
public static String extractFileName(final String fileName)
{
    final int dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    return dotIndex < 0 ? fileName : fileName.substring(0,dotIndex);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything complicated about a regex. Like `\.([^.]*)$`. I guess if you don't know regex at all any regex you see is too complicated.

Comment: Complicated in the sense that the complexity of the solution does not correspond to the complexity of the original requirement. Starting a regular expression engine to find a dot in a string is just a waste of resources. Knowing regular expressions also means when not to use regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Simply put, if `.*(?=\.)` matches, return it. Or is last index and substring really a better solution. Nah, it isn't.

Comment: Testing your solution on my machine 1.000.000 times takes about 240 - 270 ms. I even precompiled the pattern to have a fair competition. Testing my solution the same 1.000.000 times takes 20 - 30 ms. That's a factor of about 10. I hope that clarifies my point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx instead:

```
 ^\\(.+\\)*(.+)\.(.+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just use substring. `String.substring` is used for this purpose. In your case, you could simply use `str.substring(0, str.length - 3)` to get everything but the last 3 characters from the string. Besides this, you could use `str.split`.