# Add files and folders to the sheet

Tags: java

How to run through the folder with subfolders and files and put them in a list of files and a list of directories?

I tried to put only files. I got out, maybe there is a better way?

```
public List<File> getFileList(String directoryPath, ArrayList<File> files) {
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File[] filesList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : filesList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (!(file.isDirectory())) {
                if (file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")).equals(".xml")) {
                    files.add(file);
                }
            }
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            this.getFileList(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

I want to have a total of two lists with directories and files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `File` can't have both [`File#isDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory--) and [`File#isFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile--) be true a the same time. So this

```java
if (file.isFile()) {
            if (!(file.isDirectory())) {
```

is not necessary. The first `if` is enough for a `File` being a normal file and not a directory.

You try to collect only files that end with `.xml`. Note that testing the part of the filename starting with the first dot `.` is not a stable way to do this. Consider a file named `foo.bar.baz.xml`. Your approach would check for `.bar.baz.xml` being equal to `.xml`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16202288/11044402) for how to do this in a stable way.

Comment: I need .xml files

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood. Please note that your code code has a bug that will miss files whose names ends with `.xml` but who contain more than one dot. Check out the answer I've linked to.

Comment: @ILYAYARATS Two other likely bugs: 1/ you will miss anything that ends with ".XML", ".Xml"... 2/ If there is no dot in the name, indexOf returns -1, and substring will throw an exception. The usual way to deal with this: cut at the *last* dot, *if any*, or get the last 4 characters of the name, if there are at least 4 characters. Then convert to lowercase and compare to ".xml".