# How to split string into sentences in android and java?

Tags: java, android, regex, split

Split method not working with "." in android and java .

```
String[] extension = selectedItem.getmName().split(".");
```

Comment: Try escaping the '.' - that is regex for "any character".

Comment: You can use `substring(selectedItem.getmName().indexOf('.')+1)` instead.

Comment: Thanks its working now

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
String[] extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(selectedItem.getName())
```

Reference : [How do I get the file extension of a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Upvoted for other way than regex.

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape the ".":

```
String[] sentences = selectedItem.getmName().split("\\.");
```

Since "." is regex for any character the result would always be an array of 0 length since every character is a delimeter and `split` only returns what is *not* a delimeter - which would be nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] sentences = selectedItem.getmName().split("\\.");
```

This must works. This is a special situation for dot.