# How can i find the extension of files in a specific folder in Android using subString()

Tags: java, android

How can i find the extension of files in a specific folder in Android using subString() function in Java? or you can also suggest me the best way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the file extension of a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

```java
String fileName = "document.old.pdf";
String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); // pdf
```