# Java getting file extension without substring

Tags: java, file-extension

How do I get file extension in Java without using that silly `lastIndexOf('.')` etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I trim a file extension from a String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: possible not.
Any solution there is using lastIndexOf

Comment: A little background into why `lastindexof` isn't what you want or isn't working for you - sure I know this is approach has issues as well, but a little understanding as to why you are looking for another approach might help.

Comment: I guess the other libraries also would follow the same method. In fact FileNameUtils use the same mechanism. But i wonder why you dont want that. Do you think it will fail for some cases. If so can u state an example of failure with this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The apache Commons library has [`FilenameUtils.getExtension()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29).

You can look over the source starting [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/), and [FilenameUtils](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.java).

At least look over their implementation. It's pretty simple, they handle *dir.ext/file* correctly, and to handle something like *file.tar.gz* you'll need a special case if you want to extract *.tar.gz* rather than just *.gz*.

Comment: I had interpreted that he wanted the file extension itself, not the name without the extension.  There is still a method for that (`getExtension`), but read what it does: *"returns the textual part of the filename after the last dot."*  That's exactly what he's already doing; there's no point in adding an entire library/dependency just for the same functionality (unless he's already using Apache Commons).

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis that is, right about my method mixup. I believe that the implementation of `getExtension` is a bit more thorough that simply wrapping a `lastIndexOf`, for reasons that your own answer addresses, and e.g. _dir.ext/file_.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a standard library, so it is overkill for the probblem, i used lastIndexOf

Answer (score 2):

That's probably the easiest way (also note that depending on the context, it's not necessarily correct, e.g. ".tar.gz").

You could also `split` the string based on the `.` character and take the last piece, but that seems just as difficult.

Is there a particular reason *why* you're trying to avoid `substring` and `lastIndexOf`?

Answer (score 1):

Do not want to include external libraries? Use regular expressions:

```
String extension = filename.replaceAll("^.*\\.([^.]+)$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

With [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getFileExtension%28java.lang.String%29)

`Files.getFileExtension("some.txt")`

Comment: I am afraid there is no such method in [jdk8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), I guess you mean google's [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#getFileExtension%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @A4L thanks for pointing this out, I got confused by java.lang package of this class ☺