# How to determine which FileChooser ExtensionFilter has been selected - javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, apache-pivot

I having trouble related to javafx filechooser component. In filechooser javafx doesn't provide a way to get selected extension type(file extension selected in save as dropdown). Same issue is also mentioned [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2390374). It is fixed in javafx 8 version. see [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2390374) .it requires login. I am using javafx 2.2. Can somebody suggest a workaround for same using javafx 2.2?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with Swing?

Comment: Well i thought some swing developer might have some useful info on this.

Comment: Why?  And if so, why not toss AWT into the mix?  If you want a `JFileChooser` use one and stop asking silly questions, otherwise there is really no connection.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i can't use JFileChooser in my javafx application as javafx doesn't allow this...Its a perfectly valid question and there is connection too...its just that you are not getting it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be already implemented &/ or fixed.
If what you exactly want is still no working for you with the latest javaFx version, than i guess you should use poj or apache commons:

The apache Commons library has [`FilenameUtils.getExtension()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) or maybe: [Java getting file extension without substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603658/java-getting-file-extension-without-substring/11603687#11603687)

---

- Note: The ticket indirect metioned by you (http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18836) is fixed since Feb, 8 2013 03:25 PM and they have also a test class for this in the ticket that, may help you: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/attachment/27646/TestFileChooser.java, just sign up and login to see all the related information ...
- Another interesting thread around this issue: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?421412.html%29

Comment: thanks for the response @4F2E4A2E but what i require is different...In the filechooser dialog i need to get the extension selected in the save as type....he should not be required to specify the file extension...the application should get it from the save as type selected by user..and the fix is available in java 8 but i cant use javafx 8 ...so i need some other alternative...

Comment: Please post a snippet, thy!