# Java - How to get the name of a file from the absolute path and remove its file extension?

Tags: java, string, file

I have a problem here, I have a String that contains a value of C:\Users\Ewen\AppData\Roaming\MyProgram\Test.txt, and I want to remove the C:\Users\Ewen\AppData\Roaming\MyProgram\ so that only Test is left. So the question is, how can i remove any part of the string.

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Are you asking this in a more general direction of how to remove parts of a string, or specifically for strings containing file paths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working strictly with file paths, try this

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\Ewen\\AppData\\Roaming\\MyProgram\\Test.txt";
File f = new File(path);
System.out.println(f.getName()); // Prints "Test.txt"
```

---

> Thanks but I also want to remove the .txt

OK then, try this

```
String fName = f.getName();
System.out.println(fName.substring(0, fName.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java) for more information.

Comment: Thanks but I also want to remove the .txt

Comment: @mre haha that is exactly what I tried to avoid with my answer D:

Comment: @mre, `fName.substring(fName.lastIndexOf('.'))` is suffice.

Comment: To avoid using File(),  use: path.substring( path.lastIndexOf('\\')+1, path.lastIndexOf('.') )

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class has all the necessary power to deal with this. Methods you may be interested in:

`String.split()`, `String.substring()`, `String.lastIndexOf()`

Those 3, and more, are described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Give it some thought, and you'll have it working in no time :).

Comment: If you're working strictly with file paths, I think it's easier to just use the `File` class rather than `String.split` to parse the file name.

Comment: Easier it is, but I don't think we should give such a shortcut (which involves extra objects, and dealing with a type semantically outside the immediate domain of the problem, which is strings) to someone that would ask this question in the first place :)
What will he do when it's `:` and not `/` delimiting his paths?

Comment: Well, you're right in that my solution isn't flexible, nor elegant, but it is concise! :D

Comment: Oh no I think your approach is **way** more elegant than mine (concise = elegant most of the time!). I would actually do it your way myself, it's just not very educational :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [FilenameUtils.getBaseName(String filename)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName%28java.lang.String%29). The `FilenameUtils` class is a part of [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

According to the documentation, the method "will handle a file in either Unix or Windows format".  "The text after the last forward or backslash and before the last dot is returned" as a String object.

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\Ewen\\AppData\\Roaming\\MyProgram\\Test.txt";
String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filename);
System.out.println(baseName);
```

The above code prints `Test`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DieterMeemken: I added an example to my answer.