# How to get rid of the file type when using getName()?

Tags: java

Only doing this because I am lazy. I just wrote a program to list all my music into an excel file.

```
   import java.io.*;
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

      public class NewClass {

        public static void main( String args[] ) 
        {
           File folder = new File("C:/Users/Public/Music/OldMusic");
           File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
             try{
                 FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.xls"), listOfFiles[i].getName(), true);
                 BufferedWriter output;
                 output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.xls", true));
                 output.newLine();
                 output.close();
             }
             catch (IOException e){
             }
          }
      }
     }
```

The code works fine, but at the end of every song there is *.mp3* (i.e.: *Metallica - Nothing Else Matters.mp3*).

Is there a way just to have the Name of the song without the *.mp3* at the end of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I trim a file extension from a String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: *"the Name of the song without the .mp3 at the end of it?"*  I have a collection of MP3s in which the name of the file is often not closely related to the title of the track, which is itself better expressed in the **ID3 v. 2** tags embedded in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
String fname = listOfFiles[i].getName();
fname.substring(0, fname.lastIndexOf("."))
```

Instead of passing..

```
listOfFiles[i].getName()
```

Comment: That is becoming less comprehensible by the moment (mostly due to in-line code formatting).

Comment: :) I am just continually editing the answer. I hope it is looking better now.

Comment: See if you can live with my suggested edit, roll back if not.  I think it is more clear because of the (limited amount) of color and each statement being on a single line.

Comment: thank you Andrew, it looks much better. But how did you do it? Blockquote?

Comment: Select a code sample and click the `{}` button.  It inserts 4 spaces before each line of the selected text, and the rest is handled automagically.  I often just insert the 4 spaces manually, but make sure the code 'block' has a blank line between it and preceding text (without the blank line, the formatting software gets confused).

Comment: hmmm... I did use {} option by pressing Ctrl+k but it was wrapping line then.

Comment: Thank you this works like a charm lastIndexOf(".") was the only difference between you and Toms answers.

Comment: *".. it was wrapping line then."*  Huhh.  Note that when I was 1st editing it, the last ` (from in-line code formatting) was enough to make it line wrap.  Only after removing all of the acutes did it reduce to a single line (with no horizontal scroll-bar).

Comment: will remember it. Thanks Andrew :).

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using `FileUtils`, note that you get methods for handling extensions.

See [`FileUtils.removeExtension`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#removeExtension%28java.lang.String%29).

Look through the code and you'll see that these methods for handling filename extensions - also `getExtension`, `isExtension` - all just use `lastIndexOf`, so they'll only handle the simple cases, but this should be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: +1, this surely is more readable than the direct lastIndexOf solution. And that one dereferences the array element twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

  public class NewClass {

    public static void main( String args[] ) 
    {
       File folder = new File("C:/Users/Public/Music/OldMusic");
       File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
         try{
             FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.xls"), listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(0, listOfFiles[i].getName().indexOf(".mp3")), true);
             BufferedWriter output;
             output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.xls", true));
             output.newLine();
             output.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e){
         }
      }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You could change listOfFiles[i].getName().indexOf(".mp3") to listOfFiles[i].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(".mp3")

Comment: *"You could.."*  I ***would*** use the ID3 v. 2 tags, so 'no thanks'.

Comment: You would use the ID3 v. 2 tags for what?

Comment: For the title.  See my comment on the question.

Comment: Well yeah but that's not what he asked

Comment: That means it reached a file without the .mp3 suffix. Are you sure every file ends with this?

Comment: don't worry they are all lower case but i am getting a compile error >> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
        at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:14)
Java Result: 1

Comment: An index of -1 means that the string ".mp3" was not found in the file.  Try adding a System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName()); right before the writeStringToFile line

Comment: I am getting of the songs been printed out System.out.println() but still getting the same error at the end, going to try a different way cheers