# Remove .txt From File Name - Java

Tags: java, parsing

I'm reading in file names as Strings. I don't know how long these file names will be but I know that all end in .txt. I want to remove the .txt leaving only the file name. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, there's the obvious approach of checking that the string *does* end with `.txt`, and just taking a substring based on the original length - 4... have you tried that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: *"Any ideas?"*  Yes. Search the forum and show some effort before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (filename.endsWith(".txt")) {
    filename = filename.substring(0, filename.length()-4);
}
```

Or:

```
filename = filename.replace(".txt", "");
```

(will also cut away any .txt inside but not at the end of the file)

Comment: `filename = filename.replaceFirst("\\.txt$", "");`

Answer (score 1):

```
 int dot = file.getFileName().toString().lastIndexOf(".");
 String me = "File: " + file.getFileName().toString();
 System.out.println("File: " + file.getFileName().toString().substring(0,dot+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString.subtring(0, yourString.length()-4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(filepath.endsWith(".txt") {
    filepath = filepath.substring(0, filepath.lastIndexOf(".txt");
}
```