# How to extract a particular string from a String variable

Tags: java, string

I am getting a string which contains the name of the file along woth extension for ex as shown below..

```
 String s = "abcdf.dat";// Now as shown file abcde having a .dat extension
```

Now i want to store the file name only in another string but not the extension so I want to store in this format
 such as-

```
 String p= "abcdf"; //only file name please advise how to achieve this
```

Comment: This code does not even compile (unless `abcdf` is an object of a class that has a public field called `dat`).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java?lq=1

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OP might forgot to write `String s = "abcdf.dat";`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split(String regex)` to get the name.

```
String fileName = "abcdf.dat";
String name = fileName.split("\\.")[0]; // abcdf
String ext = fileName.split("\\.")[1]; // dat
```

**NOTE:** `"\\."` is a regular expression.

Comment: This won't work, since `.` has to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)  method.

```
String abcdf = "abcdf.dat";
String result= abcdf.split("\\.")[0];
```

`.`  is a meta character ,So you need to escape it before splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use-

```
String filename = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("."));
```

> Since File name can contain more than one dot (.) so till last dot
>   would be the file name.

Comment: How about "filename.tar.gz" ?

Comment: @bsd these(.tar.gz or .9.png etc) are exceptional case you can keep check for it pragmatically.

Comment: @TarunDroid  We can't cover all the aspects here.We give some hints,Help to resolve some Logical mistakes etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "abcdf.dat";

String start = StringUtils.substringBefore(s, "."); // returns "abcdf"
```

Comment: What if file name have more than one dot like `some.file.doc`?

Answer (score 0):

```
String p = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 String fileName = "abcdf.dat";

 String name = fileName.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("."))[0];
 String ext = fileName.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("."))[1];
```