# How to create a file in java so that the extension does not appear in the name of file?

Tags: java, file, io

I want to create a file in windows with java program with the help of the attached program but whenever I do that the extension name appears in the file name.I want extension of this file to be txt on windows.How do I rectify this problem.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello world";
        try {
            File file = new File("example.txt");
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(text);
            output.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the extension name appears in the file name"?  Where does it appear?  If you were creating a file `example.txt` but the `.txt` is showing up in a Windows Explorer window and you weren't expecting it to, the problem is with your Windows settings, not with the Java program.

Comment: Sorry, this is windows filenames question, not Java.

Comment: Ehh, this is completly diffrent question now :/

Comment: you mean the solution provided by @user2720864 is irrelevant.

Comment: No I mean, your question is irrelevant :) Your problem is wrong filename or wrong filename visible in Windows? What is your problem? Is filename ok?

Comment: I think you need to delete this question and ask a new one, probably with a "windows-explorer" tag.  If you create a file whose name ends in `.txt`, it will have a `.txt` extension.  If you want a file with a `.txt` extension but you don't want to see the `.txt` in a list of files, then it's a Windows Explorer question.  It has nothing to do with your program or with any programming language.

Comment: I think he will still be able to open it with notepad .. only he needs to choose the program to open with manually

Comment: Are all the other text files on your computer also shown as example2.txt? And this file shows as example.txt (but not example.txt.txt or anything stupid like that)

Comment: I think @ajb is right, this is the problem with windows-explorer

Comment: @Krishna "Problem" is possibly a bit harsh. Personally I hate it when an operating system has been set up so the file extention isn't shown

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `.txt` extension like

```
    File file = new File("example")
```

Comment: what will be the extension of this file on windows pc

Comment: you intent to remove the extension isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
File file = new File("example.txt")
```

To

```
File file = new File("example")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, remove extension from filename `example.txt` -> `example`. Read about [file extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension). The file format is not changed. To open this file simply use Load any file option.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Hello world";
    try {
        File file = new File("example");
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(text);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can read about removing filename extension here: [How do I trim a file extension from a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: what will be the format of this file

Comment: Format is specified by content, not by extensions. Content is not unchanged.

Comment: what will be the extension of this file on windows pc

Comment: There is no extension at all, file without extension. Yes, this is possible.

Comment: yep this is possible but I want to have an extension

Comment: I dont understant what is wrong with your program. Your program always create files with `.txt` extension.