# Java - Getting file name without extension from a folder

Tags: java, filenames

I'm using this code to get the absolute path of files inside a folder

```
public void addFiles(String fileFolder){
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();     
        fileOp.getFiles(fileFolder, files);
}
```

But I want to get only the file name of the files (without extension). How can I do this?

Comment: remove the extension from file name

Comment: i guess your example code is irrelevant to the question. please try to give the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do the work of removing the extension and printing name of file:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\abc\\some";
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        String fileName;
        int lastPeriodPos;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isFile()) {
                fileName = files[i].getName();
                lastPeriodPos = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                if (lastPeriodPos > 0)
                fileName = fileName.substring(0, lastPeriodPos);
                System.out.println("File name is " + fileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are ok with standard libraries then use Apache Common as it has ready-made method for that.

Answer (score 2):

i don't think such a method exists. you can get the filename and get the last index of `.` and truncate the content after that and get the last index of `File.separator` and remove contents before that.

you got your file name.

or you can use `FilenameUtils` from [apache commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#removeExtension(java.lang.String)) and use the following

`FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileName);`

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good way to do this - you can use [FilenameUtils.removeExtension](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#removeExtension%28java.lang.String%29).

Also, See: [How to trim a file extension from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myAppPackageName/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180813_124701_-894962406.jpg"


String nameWithoutExtension = Files.getNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses Spring you can use:

```java
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
// …
StringUtils.stripFilenameExtension("/tmp/myFile.txt") // → "/tmp/myFile"
```

**NB**: This method has its limitations when it comes to dotfiles, where it will return `/tmp/` for `/tmp/.config` (**`getBaseName()` from commons-io has the same problem** btw).

---

[This Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-filename-without-extension#removing-the-extensions-from-a-filename) proposes this nifty two-liner (basically) that claims to work for all cases:

```java
public static String removeFileExtension(String filename, boolean removeAllExtensions) {
    if (filename == null || filename.isEmpty()) {
        return filename;
    }

    String extPattern = "(?<!^)[.]" + (removeAllExtensions ? ".*" : "[^.]*$");
    return filename.replaceAll(extPattern, "");
}
```