# Regex to get filename with or without extension from a path

Tags: java, regex, string

Looking for a regex to extract out the filename part excluding the extension from a path in this code

```
String filename = fullpath.replaceFirst(regex, "$1")
```

e.g. for starter, here is the most simple case and what I have done:

- /path/filename.ext -> filename (`fullpath.replaceFirst(".*/(.*)\\..*", "$1")`)

Here are some more advance cases that I need help with:

- /filename.ext -> filename (can start with /)
- filename. -> filename (can end with .)
- /filename -> filename (can have no .)
- filename.ext -> filename (can have no /)
- filename -> filename (can have no . and /)
- .filename -> .filename (can start with .)
- /path/.filename -> .filename (can start with . right after /)
- filename.part1.ext -> filename.part1 (can have middle .)
- /path_a/path.b/ -> (empty string) (can have no filename)
- /path_a/path.b/filename -> filename (can have . in path before /)

---

Edited:
There is no actual file here and the `fullpath` does not lead to any file. It is coming from a URL request.

Comment: `new File(fullpath).getName()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that failed many cases above unfortunately.

Comment: cause you say that a folder is no file. Once you filter out the folders, it works 100%. But folders are files and have names too tho. Also the extension is usually part of the name

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I am not too sure what you are talking about? And I tried your code, it did not give correct answers. And I did not mention folder anywhere, why are you saying folder?

Comment: `/path_a/path.b/` is a valid path to a folder instead of a file. Yet it still has a name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/990408/7109162 + `new File(fullpath).getName()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you confuse me a lot here. I said I tried your code, it did not give correct result already, why are you still promoting it? `new File("/path/filename.ext").getName()` gives "filename.ext" not "filename" that I required in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trim a file extension from a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I read the link, but no I am not dealing with actual file here. Its an incoming request in URL that I need to extract the filename part from it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following regex will match desired parts:

```
^(?:.*\/)?([^\/]+?|)(?=(?:\.[^\/.]*)?$)
```

Explanation:

- `^` Match start of the line
- `(?:` Start of a non-capturing group

  - `.*\/` Match up to last `/` character
- `)?` End of the non-capturing (optional)
- `([^\/]+?|)` Capture anything but `/` ungreedily or nothing
- `(?=` Start of a positive lookahead

  - `(?:\.[^\/.]*)?` Match an extension (optional)
  - `$` Assert end of the line
- `)` End of the positive lookahead

but if you are dealing with a multi-line input string and need a bit faster regex try this one instead (with `m` flag on) :

```
^(?:[^\/\r\n]*\/)*([^\/\r\n]+?|)(?=(?:\.[^\/\r\n.]*)?$)
```

**See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/9FUtDb/1)**

Filename would be captured in the first capturing group.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems yours is working in the demo, but I can't put it in my java code, it seems the syntax is a bit different?

Comment: @user1589188 Yes, where is one backslash you need two.

Comment: Yes I did that. Please help me out here `"/path/filename.ext".replaceFirst("^(?:.*\\/)?([^\\/]+?|)(?=(?:\\.[^\\/.]*)?$)", "$1")` this does not print "filename" but "filename.ext". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1589188 You shouldn't use a replacement method here but if you have to, you should change positive lookahead to a simple matching cluster: `"/path/filename.ext".replaceFirst("^(?:.*\\/)?([^\\/]+?|)(?:\\.[^\\/.]*)?$", "$1")`

Comment: @user1589188 This also can be helpful https://regex101.com/r/9FUtDb/1/codegen?language=java

Comment: Thank you, the code in the comment did it. Although I don't understand why the difference, but there you go, points for you!

Comment: Very impressive ! Great job @revo ! That's working well and your explanation are perfect, thank you.

Comment: `^(?:.*[\\/])?([^\\/]+?|)(?=(?:\.[^\\/.]*)?$)`
It works in both Windows (\\) and Unix (/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getName()` function on a `File` object and then remove the extension using a Regex and you can check if it's a file too:

```java
File file = new File(fullpath);
if (file.isFile()) return file.getName().replace("\..*", "");
else return "";
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not working on actual files. In fact, I am dealing with a request URL, so there is no file for me to check.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the input. Should be helpful to others if they have files to work on.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer would the `isFile()` check actually work with a path that is non-existent on the file system?

Comment: If the file doesn't actually exists, then `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` both return `false`

Comment: But then the OP is right, if he doesn't have the file on disk, this method won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the path file (String pathFile) to get the name file with extension and remove it with `FilenameUtils.removeExtension`

```
String nameDocument = pathFile.substring(pathFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(nameDocument);
```

Comment: Hey thank you. I guess it is helpful for others. But in my case, it seems "/path/.filename" does not give ".filename" using that util.