# how to split String of filenames in java

Tags: java, string

In my javaFx application I am comparing mp4 names with the names of png and if they are the same it will be rendered in an imageView. Problem is the way I did it it also takes the file ending (.mp4 or .png) as name and then says it is different. Is there a way to say the comparison only should be until the last letter before the . ? I tried to use split but it did not really work

this is my current code:

```
 if (listOfFiles[i].getName().contains(imglistOfFiles[j].getName())) {
                System.out.println("Identische namen" + imglistOfFiles[j].getName());

            }
```

Comment: See `String` methods: `substring(..)` and `lastIndexOf(..)`.

Comment: You basically want to remove the extension from the filename before comparing them, right? Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the file extensions part. You can do it with `replace()` method of String:

```
if (listOfFiles[i].getName().replaceAll("(\\..+)$","").equals
          (imglistOfFiles[j].getName().replaceAll("(\\..+)$",""))) {
    System.out.println("Identische namen" + imglistOfFiles[j].getName().replaceAll("(\\..+)$",""));

}
```

The regex `"\\..+$"` searches for extensions at the end of the file's name.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it but it still shows the extension when I for example do this
                    System.out.println(imglistOfFiles[j].getName().replace("\\..+$",""));
the if statement still fails.

Comment: hey thanks, now it works just as I wanted to have it

Comment: This is a good answer if the file name is like `filename.ext`, but I have seen plenty of files with names like `file.name.ext`. I would use `String::lastIndexOf`.

Comment: This will also match, eg, `file.mp4` and `file.name.png`, which I don’t think is the intention. You could use something like `replace(“\\.[^\\.]+$”, “”)`