# How Do I Split A String With A Character That Has Multiples of the Same Character?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to parse a string in a way that is probably uncommon. I can't find the answer anywhere online. This string involves the directory path of the uploaded picture in the ImageView. Directory string have multiple "/" characters in them. How do I tell the app to look at the last "/" character in the string? Here is an example...

Directory Location of the Uploaded Image in the ImageView...

```
/storage/emulated/0/My Pictures/My family photo.png
```

I want to split that string to only show `My family photo`. The folders and the dot extension I want removed. Only the file name should be displayed.

I've tried this...

```
String s = getAbsolutePath; //This contains the full string location in my example above.
String[] split1 = s.split("/");
String newS = split1[1];
String[] split2 = newS.split(".png");
String titleString = split2[0];
```

`titleString` should now contain this data string **My family photo**.

But the result output is actually `storage`

So now, how do I code this to tell the app look at the last `/` in the string just before the filename?

I appreciate the help! Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: split the array on `/`, find the last valid index of your array. last valid index is the size of your array minus 1, so this is probably something like `split[size -1]`. -1 because arrays are zero based, while size will return the amount of items in the array, so one item doesn't mean it's at index 1, it's at 0

Comment: Can't you just create a File object and use `file.getName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with regular expressions:

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/My Pictures/My family photo.png";
String filename = path.replaceAll(".*/(.*)\\.png","$1");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way:

```
    String path = "/storage/emulated/0/My Pictures/My family photo.png";
    System.out.println(Paths.get(path).toFile().getName().replace(".png", ""));
```

Furthermore I suggest to discover package `java.nio.*` there is so much usefull tolls if you are dealing with file system.

Comment: It's a very clean solution, just for the extension removal part I would suggest to consider this post: [How do I trim a file extension from a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

After your first split you get an array with the following elements:

```
{"", "storage", "emulated", "0", "My Pictures", "My family photo.png"}
```

So in your 3rd line where you wrote `split1[1]` you are getting the second element of the above array, which is `storage`. In your case, you want to get the last element. So change your code to this:

```
String s = getAbsolutePath; //This contains the full string location in my example above.
String[] split1 = s.split("/");
String newS = split1[split1.length - 1];
String[] split2 = newS.split(".png");
String titleString = split2[0];
```

`split1.length - 1` is the index of the last element in your array, which is `My family photo.png`

Answer (score 0):

Result is "My family photo"

```
  String x = "/storage/emulated/0/My Pictures/My family photo.png";
  
  int index = x.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 ;

  x =  x.substring(index , x.lastIndexOf("."));
```